# can't import socket.io gives syntax error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

what is wrong with the following

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
```

I get an error

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
    
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I got it from their documentation. I am running NodeJS 11.15 because they've stopped maintaining NodeJS for the Rasberry Pi 1